# get instance from Controller object in NSImageView (cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm new to Objective-C.

I had make a little application with an Image Well (NSImageView) and some Buttons.
To receive the actions from the Buttons and Labels. I created a Class named "Controller". I have connected this class using the "Object" object to the InterfaceBuilder file.

For the Image Well, I created a class to inherits from NSImageView (DImageView) and set this class as class for the ImageWell (using the interfaceBuilder)

In this class I had overwritten the mouseDown Method:

```
//Class DImageView
- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

Now I want to call an method which is defined in the class Controller from this method.

But if I create a new instance of the controller object with [[Controller alloc] init]. I'm creating an new instance and can't access the IBOutlets in the Controller class right?

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for the help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link it via xib file:

[image]

And consider overriding acceptsFirstResponder too, otherwise you will not get any mouse event.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand our answer completely. I don't want to have an instance from the DImageView class in the Object. I wan't to have an instace of the Controller Object in the DImageView class. How can I link from the class to the Object in Objects?

Comment: In your xib do the same of the figure, but drag from "controller" to your image view.

Comment: I have done this. But when I drag from the Controller to the image view I have an IBOutlet in the Controller from type of the DImageView.

But I need an reference in the DImageView pointing to the controller. I need the other direction ...

Comment: Do the opposite then, can't you do that?

Comment: I can do the opposite, but then I have the Problem that the Controller import the "DImageView" class and the DImageView class import "Controller" class. That causes into several compiler errors.

Comment: Then to avoid the circular import, declare the outlet using it's direct subclass name.

Comment: Sorry Ramy can you explain it a little more detailed please?

Comment: You declare an IBOutlet of type NSObject (or whatever subclass of Controller) and bind it to the controller.